# Azure Blob Container CSV to Azure Table Storage using Synapse

Tags: database, azure, pipeline, azure-synapse

I have a large 700 GB CSV file in an Azure Blob Container.
I am using Azure Synapse to transform column names, and some data and sink it in a table.
I am unable to sink it to the Table Storage in another Azure Data Lake Storage account.

Why can't I choose an Azure Table Storage ? Do I have to add an intermittent Parquet layer to store data between file to table ? Please assist.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ahmad M., if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I choose an Azure Table Storage? Do I have to add an intermittent Parquet layer to store data between file to table?

Azure table storage is **not supported** in sink. Please find the below **supported sink types** as given in the documentation accordingly: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink

[image: Sink type supported]

**You can use copy data tool to transform data from azure blob storage to Table storage.**

Kindly refer the below documentation link given for `copying and transforming the data in Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics`

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory**